# FHSTwitterEngine - tweeting The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)

Tags: ios, fhs-twitter-engine

Tweeting through FHSTwitterEngine with my secret& consumer key  I get an error message as follows :
The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)

How ever I am sucessfully getting the auth token and the oauth_token_secret.
Also I get the time line data but not able to tweet.

For tweeting internally the engine is using this url :
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json

Please provide some help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the simulator, try opening up the Settings app in the simulator and setting up the Twitter account you are planning to use. If I were you, I would delete the entire app from the simulator and run it again, fresh. Good luck!